# Typeorm: provide default value for boolean with Mongo database

Tags: mongodb, boolean, default-value, typeorm

I am using typeorm with Mongo database. I want to provide a default value for a column with `boolean` datatype.

My entity looks as following:

```
@ObjectIdColumn()
  id: ObjectID;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  startDate: Date;

  @Column()
  endDate: Date;

  @Column()
  inspectionTypeId: string;

  @Column()
  questions: string[];

  @Column('boolean', {default: true})
  isActive: boolean;
```

However, when I save into the repo, `isActive` column is not added.

Comment: Official example usage can be seen here, for reference:
https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/column

Answer (score 20):

You can do this:

```
@Column('boolean', {default: true})
isActive: boolean = true;
```

if you don't pass a value to isActive it will be true, if you pass a value it will be this value.

Comment: I'm currently using TypeORM v0.2.29 with a postgres database and this solution worked perfectly for me.  I know the original question was about MongoDB but hopefully this helps someone else who stumbles upon this thread.

Answer (score 14):

I've faced with the same problem in fact. So my stack is the same (MongoDB + TypeORM). I have the same `isActive` field in the model and what I wanted to do is to set it 'false' by default. I tried to set 'false' and couldn't reach the goal.

I re-read multiple times this part (https://typeorm.io/#/entities)

> default: string - Adds database-level column's DEFAULT value.

and got the idea that the `default` option doesn't work for boolean types at all (maybe I'm wrong).

So in order to set it, I used `beforeInsert` hook.

```
  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    select: false,
  })
  isActive: boolean;

  @BeforeInsert()
  beforeInsertActions() {
    this.isActive = false;
  }
```

More about hooks: https://typeorm.io/#/listeners-and-subscribers

Comment: That doesn't really set a default value. Doesn't that always set it to false, so if a value did exist it would not be overwritten to false

Comment: You could use `this.isActive ??= false` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to write this:

```js
@Column({type:'boolean', default:true})
isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@Column({ type: 'boolean', default: true})
```

Comment: I used it simply as :
@Column({ default: true })
myField: boolean;
and it worked fine.
Moreover, the option indeed exists in TypeORM ColumnOptions :
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/e42091e1506148ba761737d7977331b5c1d60307/src/decorator/options/ColumnOptions.ts#L67